# Swipe from left border to open activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is there a way to open another activity/fragment (with camera in my case) by swiping left to right. But it should open not after you've finished your swipe gesture, but it should gradually appear while you are swiping . You pull another activity/fragment out from the left side. Like you can open camera on Instagram:
[image: Start swiping on Instagram]

[image: Finishing swiping on instagram]

Comment: Sorry but on Whatsapp and Instagram there are 2 different things, Whatsapp is having something similar to a ViewPager and Instagram have "Swipe" from left to right (not from the center to the right border, just from left to right). So Not sure what do you want to achieve, can you be more specific?

Comment: @denis_lor Yes, sorry, my fault. I want to achieve Instagram behaviour. To open camera by swiping form left to right. And when you begin your gesture, the camera begins to launch. After googling for a while, I suppose I can't achieve this with using 2 different activites, but how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case you want to achieve a similar navigation as in Instagram you should note that the navigation/UX is based on a `ViewPager` (consisting of `fragments`/pages) and the camera fragment will be implemented with its own `SurfaceView` (camera). [Controlling The Camera](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) and [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) documentation from google should be able to make you go forward with it.